# Matlab Javabuilder related issue

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment, javabuilders

I've written certain code in Matlab which upon execution produces list of similar results. I've done testing with lots of images on matlab.

However, to integrate it with Java, I've used javabuilder.

the only problem is that after building, the jar file upon calling the function returns simple list of images rather than relevant images.

Can anyone explain me why this is happening?

Are there any bugs with java builder?

I've rebuilt the jar file several times but results r still not the same.

Answer (score 0):

after a long trial and error session, I've found the bug. Earlier I was sending my parameters which were getting passed as integer. So, all the calculations were getting performed as integer so all the values as zero and hence no result at all..

Now, I'm sending my parameter by parsing them into double to get the correct result..

and its working as per expectation..